# ERROR: undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a code to calculate the age of a person, which worked perfectly, and it just stopped working.

Model:

```
def age
   now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    now.year - fechanacimiento.year - ((now.month > fechanacimiento.month || (now.month == fechanacimiento.month && now.day >= fechanacimiento.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  end
```

My view:

```
<%= patient.age %>
```

Comment: `fechanacimiento` is nil

Comment: Thank you very much, I saved an empty date before doing the validations and I did not refresh the database and I did not see it, that is why it gave me the error. regards

Answer (score 0):

```
def age
   now = Time.now.utc.to_date   
   fechanacimiento && now.year - fechanacimiento.year - ((now.month > fechanacimiento.month || (now.month == fechanacimiento.month && now.day >= fechanacimiento.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end
```

Comment: The code in this answer might be correct, but to be a full answer you add an explanation to help readers understand what the root of the original problem and how this addresses it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use the database to calculate the age.

Postgres:

```
patients = Patient.select(
  'patients.*',
  'AGE(patients.date_of_birth) AS age'
)
```

MySQL:

```
patients = Patient.select(
  'patients.*',
  'TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date_of_birth, CURDATE()) AS age'
)
```

The advantage is that you can order and group the records by age if needed.